Why is canvasx(winfo_x()) returning incorrect values when the widget is not visible on the screen in customtkinter in python?
Here is my problem :
I try to developp an app using customtkinter in python. On the app, I have a scrollable canvas with another canvas as a widget. I would like to get the canvas coordinates of the widget. When the widget is visible on the screen, canvasx(widget.winfo_x()) seems to work perfectly fine. It doesn't change with the amount scrolled.
The problem is when the widget is no longer visible : canvasx(widget.winfo_x()) returns a value that doesn't match the one when the widget is visible. It seems to increase with the amount scrolled.
**My goal is to get the widget canvas position when it is invisible, then make it visible by scrolling and then get a position that would be equal to the invisible one and vice-versa. **
I have tried to add or substract the amount scrolled but it doesn't solve the problem. I noticed that widget.winfo_x() does not change with the scroll when the widget is invisible. I think it might be the reason why canvasx(widget.winfo_x()) is returning incorrect values but I am not sure.
Here is a reproducible code :
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
class Canvas_composants(ctk.CTkCanvas):
    """The main canvas which is scrollable"""
    def __init__(self,master,bg):
        super().__init__(master=master,bg=bg)
        self.pack(fill="both",expand=True)
    
        # Scrollbar 
        self.hbar=ctk.CTkScrollbar(self,orientation="horizontal")
        self.hbar.pack(side='top',fill='x')
        
        #Configuration scrollbar and canvas
        self.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hbar.set)
        self.hbar.configure(command=self.xview)
        
        #Configuration of the scrollregion
        self.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,50000,50000))
        
        # Bind scroll to mousewheel
        self.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.scroll_canvas)
        
    def scroll_canvas(self,event):
        """Function executed when the mousewheel is used"""
        if event.delta:
            self.xview_scroll(-1 * (event.delta // 120), "units")

class dessin_composant(ctk.CTkCanvas):
    """How to define the object inside the main canvas"""
    def __init__(self,master,width,height,bg,x,y):
        super().__init__(master,width=width,height=height,bg=bg)
        
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        #Positionning the object 
        self.master.create_window(self.x,self.y, window=self)
        
        #Attributes 
        self.master = master
        self.canvas_hbar=self.master.hbar # The scrollbar of the main canvas

class App(ctk.CTk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Executed when closed
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.Fermeture) 
        
        # Screen resolution
        screen_x  = int(self.winfo_screenwidth())
        screen_y  = int(self.winfo_screenheight())
        
        self_X = screen_x
        self_Y = screen_y
        
        posX = (screen_x // 2) -(self_X // 2)
        posY = (screen_y // 2) -(self_Y // 2)
        
        geo="{}x{}+{}+{}".format(self_X,self_Y,posX,posY)
        self.geometry(geo)
        
        #Button

        self.frame=ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        self.frame.pack(side='left',fill='both')
        self.B=ctk.CTkButton(self.frame,text="print",command=self.f1)
        self.B.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=100)
        
        #Labels
        self.label1=ctk.CTkLabel(self.frame,text="Winfo_x()          = ")
        self.label1.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.label2=ctk.CTkLabel(self.frame,text="Canvasx(Winfo_x()) =  ")
        self.label2.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.label3=ctk.CTkLabel(self.frame,text="Canvasx(scroll)    =  ")
        self.label3.grid(row=3,column=0)



        #Main canvas
        self.c=Canvas_composants( self, "white")
        
        #Object inside canvas
        width  = 107
        height = 190
        bg     = "black"
        self.object=dessin_composant(self.c, width, height, bg,600,350)
        
    def f1(self):
        """Function which prints object position inside the main canvas"""
        #self.c.delete(self.txt)
  
        obj      = self.object
        self.off = self.c.hbar.get() # The amount scrolled

        self.label1.configure(text=f"Winfo_x()          = {obj.winfo_x()} ")
        self.label2.configure(text=f"Canvasx(Winfo_x()) = {self.c.canvasx(obj.winfo_x())} ")
        self.label3.configure(text=f"Canvasx(scroll)    = {self.c.canvasx(self.off[0])} ")
        

        
    def Fermeture(self):
        """Executed when the window is closed"""
        if tk.messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really want to quit ? "):
            matplotlib.use('module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline')
            self.quit()
            self.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Fenetre = App()
    Fenetre.mainloop()     

In the above app, if you click on the print button, the values of widget.winfo_x(), canvasx(widget.winfo_x()), and canvasx(scroll) will be printed. Thus, you can observe that canvasx(winfo_x()) changes when the widget is invisible.
Any help would be appreciated
Thank you !

when I scroll then it always change widget.winfo_x() but not canvasx(widget.winfo_x()). And it always gives canvasx(widget.winfo_x()) == canvasx(scroll) +  widget.winfo_x()

Thank you, @furas, for the reply! The issue I'm encountering is that widget.winfo_x() stops updating when the widget is invisible and scrolling continues. Consequently, as canvasx(widget.winfo_x())== canvasx(scroll) + widget.winfo_x(), canvasx(widget.winfo_x()) no longer remains constant.
My objective is to ensure that I can obtain a constante position for the widget regardless of the scrolling amount. This way, I can accurately calculate the position of another widget relative to the first one.

strange is but I always get correct equality - but I run it on Linux. But I don't know if I understand problem because widget should have always the same position on canvas from position = canvas.coords(object_id) and you can use canvas.coords(other_object_id, x, y) to move other object to correct position on canvas.

To understand it well, on linux widget.winfo_x() always changes even when the widget is invisible and you keep scrolling ?
I have tried to add self.id= self.master.create_window(self.x,self.y, window=self) in  Class dessin_composant but it returns  None when i tried to print the coordinates. I think it is because I am using a canvas instead of expected canvas.creat object. The reason why I am using a canvas as a widget is that in my true code, I drag and drop images of optical components and then get their positions with widget.winfo_x().

at this moment you have two canvas - Canvas_composants and dessin_composant - and maybe you used coords() with wrong canvas.  OR maybe problem is that it is not classic tkinter.Canvas but ctk.CTkCanvas and it may work little different.

I checked self.c.coords(obj.id) and it also gives me None but self.c.find_all() shows that there is object with id 1, and self.c.bbox(obj.id) gives me always (546, 254, 655, 446)

I found that ctk.CTkCanvas has own coords() which is missing return in code and this makes problem. There are few issues on GitHub and there is even pull request with modification. Maybe next version will have correct code. At this moment you may create own class MyCanvas(CTkCanvas) with code like in my message on GitHub, and later use MyCanvas

@furas Thanks a lot ! self.c.bbox(obj.id) works for me too ! But when I tried to modified ctk_canvas.py with your code my program stop working and I get the following error message : `File "C:\Users\Fornesa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\core_rendering\ctk_canvas.py", line 71, in _get_char_from_radius
return self.radius_to_char_fine[radius]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptableWhen I try to go back to the original version ofctk_canvas.py`, I get the same error message I don't understand why

maybe accidentally you changed something - there is original source code ctk_canvas.py. If you need coordsonly when you useCanvasthen maybe it would be simpler and safer to createclass MyCanvas(ctk.CTkCanvas)with fixeddef coords()and later useMyCanvasinstead ofctk.CTkCanvas`

It worked !! I must have made a mistake when pasting the code. Thanks again @furas for your help ^^. I will try to make my main program work with coords now.  For information, all I did is to replace the file ctk_canvas.py with the one here  (https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/8bee2425a51d7e2b27aa579829cb72f185e52d7e/customtkinter/windows/widgets/core_rendering/ctk_canvas.py)
